# Recursively execute a Python program in all subfolders

Tags: python, subdirectory

I have a program that reads all the files with ".txt" extension in a directory and makes operations with the numbers written in these files.  The program is something like that:

```
   import glob
   list_of_files = glob.glob("*.txt")
   for filename in list_of_files:
       p,j, x = open(filename, "r") 
       #do things
```

For example i could sum all the p of all the files in the folder or so.  The thing is that i have many folders with the same structure and in each one of those I need to run the same program. Since I don't want to copy paste the python program in each folder and then run it, I was searching for a way of doing it recursively.

I have found that python has a library called os which could help:

```
  for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
      for name in files:
       #do things
```

The problem is that I don't know how to be sure that the program is done once for every folder, and I fear that doing this way I could potentially consider all the files in all the subfolders at once, while I need to work with all the files in each folder sperately... in other terms I need something like:

```
  for root, dirs in os.walk(path):
      for files in dirs:
          glob.glob("*.txt)
          #do things
```

Comment: have you tried actual recursion?

Comment: Could you elaborate? I don't understand

Comment: Do all folders have a common root?

Comment: Yes, all the folders have the common root, and each folder has the same number of files

Comment: you define a function that parses through the directory and for every folder you find you execute the folder parser again.

Comment: Did you consider to use the Unix standard tool `find` to find all directories and then just execute your Python script in each of these?  `find -type d -execdir /path/to/my/python/program.py`

Comment: @Alfe in this case I would need to copy paste program.py in each folder right? or at least to modify the program itself so that accepts a path as an input

Comment: Of course not.  It has to be located at `/path/to/my/python/program.py`. Using the `-execdir` flag of `find` your program will be executed *in* each directory.  See `man find`'s section for `-execdir`.

Comment: @Alfe maybe I am missing something but running the tool says to me that is missing the argument for -execdir. What I do is:  find -type d -execdir program.py  (the program is in the root directory

Comment: My bad, sorry.  `-execdir` executes the program in the directory of the found thing.  The found thing is the directory you want to handle, so your program will be executed in the directory of the directory, i. e. its parent (stupid me).  But still:  `e() { (cd "$1"; /path/to/my/program.py); }; export -f e; find -type d -exec bash -c 'e "{}"' \;`  Now it's a bit more complex, sorry.  But this should work.  The error you got was because your argument to `-execdir` wasn't terminated with `\;` as it must be.

Comment: This is far too complex for me since I don't understand what the script does (it doesn't work, but I bet it's my fault because of the cd "$1" thing, the terminal is opened in the same folder where program.py is located  and so i don't need cd, but I am not able to remove this part without getting some error) . I am really newbie on unix/bash in general :\
Anyway, if you could answer the question with this script I would be more than happy to accept it because I think is the easiest way to go;)

Comment: I used this horrible workaround:
    for d in * /; do cp program.py "$d"; cd "$d"; python program.py; cd ..; done.     I need to go inside each folder because of glob.glob, i noticed that if i launch python folder1/program.py  it says that there are no txt files, because glob.glob("*.txt")  lists all the files in the folder where the terminal is opened...

Answer (score 0):

I´m not 100% sure on the syntax so instead I will give you a pythonized pseudocode. It calls the folder_parser for every folder it find until you passed through all layers of folders.

```
def folder_parser(dir):
    if(dir):
        for subdir in dir_list:
            if(is_a_folder()):
                folder_parser(subdir)
            elif(is_a_text()):
                do_your_text_thing()
            else: continue
    else: break
```

As Alfe suggested os.walk works as well (and probably does more or less the same thing a little faster for big directorys). It returns a generator object of tupels with 3 values, the path, a list of contained folders and a list of contained files for al folders in the directory and subdirectorys.

```
for things in os.walk(dir):
    for files in things[2]:
        if(is_a_text(files)):
            do_your_text_thing(things[0]+files)
```

Comment: Have a look at `os.walk()`.

Comment: Can i replace the if statement with  list_of_files=glob.glob('*.txt')       or something in order to mantain the program structure I already have?

Comment: @FrancescoDiLauro I´m not sure what exactly you want to replace but since glob returns a list an if statement is not something to be replaced by it. IF you are sure that files in the directorys are only text files or folders you can ignore the if statement in the os.walk part.